# Layout moves horisontell when displaying div

Tags: html, css, show-hide

I have a 3 column layout with select element. When I choose the last value in select a div displays and checkboxes appear. My problem is when I choos the last value in the select to the right, the whole layout moves.
Codepen `https://codepen.io/thpe0018/pen/yopPyK`
I have my code here: 
CSS

```
        .floatLeft{
            float: left;
        }
        .clearFloat{
            clear: both;
        }
        h3{
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            color: #555; 
            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
        }
        #PL, #SC, #EL {
            width: 250px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        select {
            padding: 4px; 
            margin: 0; 
            background: #fff; 
            width: 250px; 
            font-size: 14px; 
            color: #555; 
            border: 1px #ddd solid;
            float: left;
        }
        #compPL,#compSC,#compEL{
            width:245px;
            font-family: arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size:0.9em;

            display: none;
        }
        #fPL,#fSC,#fEL{
            font-family: arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size:0.8em;    
            color: #555;                
        }
        #compSC{
            margin-left: 260px;
        }
        #compEL{
            margin-left: 520px;
        }
        #fPL label, #fSC label, #fEL label {
            display: block;
            width: 220px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            text-indent: -25px;
        }
        input[type="checkbox"]{
            padding:0;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            /*top: -1px;*/
            *overflow: hidden;
        }
        /*****************************************************/
        /*-- End Inställningar för dropdown-box, kategori 7--*/
        /*****************************************************/
```

HTML

```
<h2>7. Avslag/Komplettering</h2>
    <div id="btn7">
                <div id="reject">
                    <div id="PL" class="floatLeft">
                        <h3>Privatlån</h3>
                        <select id="rejectPL">
                          <option value="valgBrev">Välj brev</option>
                            <optgroup label="Avslag">
                                <option value="RDS700.1_Avslag_info_kreditupplysning">Avslag info kreditupplysning</option>
                                <option value="RDS701.1_Avslag_giltighetstid">Avslag giltighetstid</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="Komplettering">
                                <option value="RDS703.1_PL_Komplettering_sammanslagen">Komplettering sammanslagen</option>
                            </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    </div> <!-- End div Privatlån -->
                    <div id="SC" class="floatLeft">
                        <h3>SupremeCard</h3>
                        <select id="rejectSC">
                            <option value="valgBrev">Välj brev</option>
                            <optgroup label="Avslag">
                                <option value="RDS710.1_ Kund_har_redan_SC">Kund har redan SC</option>
                                <option value="RDS711.1_Konvertering">Konvertering</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Komplettering">
                                    <option value="RDS713.1_SC_Komplettering">Komplettering generell</option>
                                </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div> <!-- End div SupremeCard -->
                    <div id="Ellos" class="floatLeft">
                        <h3>Ellos</h3>
                        <select id="rejectEL">
                            <option value="valgBrev">Välj brev</option>
                            <optgroup label="Avslag">
                                <option value="RDS720.1_Avslagsbrev_allmänt">Avslagsbrev allmänt</option>
                                <option value="RDS721.1_avslag_antal_inbetalningar_max_skuld">Avslag antal inbetalningar el max skuld</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Komplettering">
                                    <option value="RDS723.1_Ellos_Komplettering">Komplettering generell</option>
                                </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div> <!-- End div Ellos -->
                </div><!-- End div Reject -->
                <div id="comp" class="clearFloat">
                    <div id="compPL">
                        <fieldset id="fPL">

                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="1" />Ansökan är inte komplett</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="2" />Det saknas underskrift</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="3" />Komplettering av kontonummer el. clearingnummer</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="4" />Ansökan är ifylld med blyerts</label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div><!-- End compPL -->
                    <div id="compSC">
                        <fieldset id="fSC">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="1" />Ansökan är ifylld med blyerts</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="2" />Underskrift saknas</label>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="3" />Markerade uppgifter saknas</label>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="4" />Giltig ID-handling saknas</label>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="5" />Giltig ID-handling saknas för extrakortsinnehavare</label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div><!-- End compSC -->
                    <div id="compEL">
                        <fieldset id="fEL">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="1" />Kopia på ID-handling</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="2" />Ditt senaste besked om utbetalning</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="3" />Din senaste lönespecifikation</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="4" />Anställningsintyg</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="5" />Resultatrapport</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="6" />Blankett gällande kundkännedom</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="7" />Underskrift saknas</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="8" />Komplettering av kontonummer el. clearingnummer</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="9" />Ansökan är ifylld med blyerts</label>
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="10" />Ansökan är inte komplett</label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div><!-- End compEL -->



                    </div><!-- End comp -->
            </div><!-- End btn7 -->
```

Javascript

```
                $("#rejectPL, #rejectSC, #rejectEL").click(function(){
                var thisID = this.id;
                var optionSelected = $(this);
                var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                console.log("OptionValue " + valueSelected);
                if(valueSelected=="RDS703.1_PL_Komplettering_sammanslagen"){
                  console.log("Privatlån");
                    $("#compPL").show();
                    $("#compSC").hide();
                    $("#compEL").hide();
                }
                else if(valueSelected=="RDS713.1_SC_Komplettering"){
                    $("#compPL").hide();
                    $("#compSC").show();
                    $("#compEL").hide();
                }
                else if(valueSelected=="RDS723.1_Ellos_Komplettering"){
                    $("#compPL").hide();
                    $("#compSC").hide();
                    $("#compEL").show();
                }
                else{
                    $("#compPL").hide();
                    $("#compSC").hide();
                    $("#compEL").hide();
                }

                //Set value valgBrev
                if(thisID=="rejectPL"){
                    $("#rejectSC").val('valgBrev');
                    $("#rejectEL").val('valgBrev');
                }
                else if(thisID=="rejectSC"){
                    $("#rejectPL").val('valgBrev');
                    $("#rejectEL").val('valgBrev');
                }
                if(thisID=="rejectEL"){
                    $("#rejectPL").val('valgBrev');
                    $("#rejectSC").val('valgBrev');
                }
```

When I view it in codepen it seems to work, but in InternetExplorer or Chrome it doesn't. :-(

Therese

Comment: Welcome to SO - please include your code in the question, not just a link

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question, not just on external sites.